# useState with a lambda invokes the lambda when set

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `useState` with a void returning lambda. For example (TypeScript):

```js
const [doSomething, setDoSomething] = useState<() => void>();
```

What I'm finding is that when I call `setDoSomething`, not only does it set the state to the lambda I've defined, but it also *invokes* the lambda. For example (TypeScript):

```js
setDoSomething(() => alert("Did something!"));
```

This statement results in an alert showing "Did something!" I just want to set the state to a lambda at this point, I don't want to invoke it. I want to invoke it later by doing:

```js
doSomething();
```

I *think* maybe what's going on is that React.js is treating my lambda as a lambda to lazily get the state value, but this is not the desirable behavior in this case. Is it possible to use `useState` with lambda types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React DOES treat lambda the way you think. You can create a custom hook with `useReducer` to get around that limitation.

```
const useState2 = initVal => {
  const setter = useRef((__, next) => ({ val: next })).current
  const [wrapper, dispatch] = useReducer(setter, { val: initVal })
  const state = wrapper.val
  const setState = dispatch
  return [state, setState]
}
```

Live Demo:

```js
const { useRef, useReducer } = React

const useState2 = initVal => {
  const setter = useRef((__, next) => ({ val: next })).current
  const [wrapper, dispatch] = useReducer(setter, { val: initVal })
  const state = wrapper.val
  const setState = dispatch
  return [state, setState]
}

function App() {
  const [say, setSay] = useState2(() => console.log('something'))
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={say}>say something</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSay(() => console.log('yo!'))}>say yo! instead</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this and providing a work around. It's a bummer it works this way. Seems like it would have been better to just have an explicit type (e.g. Lazy<T>) so that lambdas would work like any other type.

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler work-around would be to wrap your lambda in another lambda:

`setDoSomething(() => () => alert("Did something!"));`

The outer lamba is invoked by React, the inner lambda is invoked by you.

Comment: The simplest thing, even in initialization: const [x,setX] = useState(() => (() => x+1))